# Sharing Salesforce Report with a user and prevent editing

Tags: profile, custom-reports

I created Salesforce report as a System Administrator that I saved in the folder ABC.
Folder ABC is shared with a user (view only).
User is using profile where Administrative Preference "Edit My Reports" is disabled.

But somehow user is still able to edit the report.
How I can prevent user from being able to edit the report?
What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: "Enhanced Folder Sharing" is enabled on my org and org was created after Summer ’13 (after that release "Enhanced Folder Sharing" was default for every org). So my understanding is that I should control ability of user to edit report or not via sharing on report folder. Which does not work...

Comment: Update: After speaking to Salesforce support, suggestion is to disable on the profile "Create and Customize Reports". Which yes, removes "Edit" button but also takes away ability for user to create his/her reports. I want them to be able to create reports... Waiting for SF to give me solution to that.